# banderole across page containing text using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a banderole (I hope that is the right word) across a page using CSS.
What I want to achieve:
[image]
Ideally the banderole should be responsive and wrapped in some element so that I can place multiple of those banderoles on one page, one below the other.
I have tried myself to build a banderole but the result is far from what I want:

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="banderole">
    <div class="banderole-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .banderole {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .banderole-content {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .section {
    background-color: black;
  }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lx4r/38gq4mhm/3/)

Is it possible to build such a banderole in css?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS transform's `translate()` and `skew()` properties.

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full page view to view it properly*):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.content-holder {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(-20deg);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
}

.top {
  top: 25%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.bottom {
  top: 75%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content-holder"></div>

<div class="text top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi molestiae repellat rerum quam quos incidunt, dolore delectus necessitatibus nobis, nesciunt dolorum odio, blanditiis minus iusto, ratione id. Est, sit, ut.</div>

<div class="text bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi molestiae repellat rerum quam quos incidunt, dolore delectus necessitatibus nobis, nesciunt dolorum odio, blanditiis minus iusto, ratione id. Est, sit, ut.</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That looks great, thanks a lot!
Would you mind explaining you usage of `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` for `top`, `bottom` and `content-holder`? For me that is confusing as the position has already been set by the `top` and `left` properties.  
Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: @lx4r It's my pleasure! The `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` is used to center the `.content-holder` as they are already set to `top: 50%` & `left: 50%` so the `transform` property is again setting `-50%` back to center from the origin. If this answer really helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `transform: skew()` Method:

```css
.banderole {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
  transform: skew(-20deg, 0);
}
.section {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="banderole">
    <div class="banderole-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/429xhrrt/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your code also rotates the text inside the banderole (apart from that it's perfect).